# Change binded value in listview

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my `listview` one of the controls is `label` which `is binded` to `BoolValue` comming from `viewmodel`, in this case `BoolValue` is bool type so value could be either `true` or `false`. Is there any way to replace it with other text? I use MVVM.

```
  <Label
       Text="{Binding BoolValue}" />
  <Label
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a [ValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters)

```
public class BoolToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value != 0) ? "True Value" : "False Value";
    }

}
```

then in your XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyDemo"
         x:Class="MyDemo.MyPage"
         >
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="BoolToString" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    ...

    <Label Text={Binding BoolValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToString}}" />

    ...
```

Comment: What i see is this converter BoolToStringConverter can only convert into two values True Value or False Value. What if another e.g label wants to have another values against false/true. Is ther possible to say for converter depending on diffrent controls that i want  diffrent values? For instance in this line: <Label Text={Binding BoolValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToString}}" />